# Достать номер элемента внутри корня

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

У меня есть treeView. В нем корень, от корня идут ветки.

Т.е скажем root->1, root->2, root->3... Вложенных деревьев нет. Т.е 1, 2, 3 это элементы сами по себе. Вопрос, как достать индекс выделенного элемента?

root

__C++

__Java

__C#

Допустим в данный момент юзер нажал на Java, как определить что номер = 2(ну или 1, все-таки с 0 нумерация, С++ это 0, Java это 1, C# это 2). Надеюсь понятно описал, если что могу подробнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{        
     label1.Text = "Text: " + e.Node.Text + " Index: "
             + e.Node.Index.ToString();            
}
```

Comment: А правильно ли я понимаю что и у корня индекс 0 и у его первого вложенного элемента тоже? И если да, выходит чтоб проверить что выбран не корень надо писать if (treeView.SelectedNode != treeView.TopNode) ?

Comment: Да, так и есть.